# Core Data Performing a fetch in performBlock on a background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

When I try to perform a fetch on a background context it says:
 [NSManagedObjectContext **Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor**] ()

On a background thread, I want to check if an object exists then update. If it doesn't I insert it and then update. For some reason xcode keeps saying I have a concurrency violation when I try to perform the fetch. Am I not allowed to perform fetches in a background context?

This is my setup for my contexts:

`Persistent store -> Root saving context -> default context (concurrency type main)
persistent store -> Root saving context -> background context (concurrency type private)`

the background context is trying to performBlock:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
    [backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        [Conversation parseConversationAndCalls:objects inContext:backgroundContext];

        ...
    }];
```

then the `parseConversationAndCalls` method call will perform a fetch:

```
+ (void) parseConversationAndCalls:(NSArray*)objects inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)localContext {
    ...
    for (NSArray *callData in conversationsCallData) {

        NSNumber *callID = [BPDObject scrubbedInteger:callData[1]];
        Call *call = (Call*) [FetchRequestHelper fetchWithClass:Call.self withID:callID inContext:localContext];  // breakpoint hit here

        if (call == nil) {
            call = [Call insertInManagedObjectContext:localContext];
        }

        [call updateWithValues:callData inContext:localContext];
        call.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

the fetchrequest helper just creates a fetch request, a FRC, then performs the fetch in a performBlock chunk:

```
    ... //here context is the same as backgroundContext and frc is the fetched results controller
    context.performAndWait {
        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to perform fetch from FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Generally a fetchedResultsController runs on the main thread because it is used to update UI.  When the fetchedResultsController was created it was given a managedObjectContext, which I strongly suspect was the main context.  So when you call `try frc.performFetch()` in the background context you are accessing the a main thread context in a background thread.

This is what I was able see in the code you shared.  There may be other violations that you have not shared.  Good luck tracking them down.

Comment: You're probably right. I ended up using a fetch request with no FRC and that worked fine.